# Converting Code from RequireJS to Webpack

Tags: javascript, requirejs, webpack, amd

How do nested requires in RequireJS change with Webpack?

```
  require([...], function(...) {

     require([...], function(...) {

         require([...], function(...) {
         });

     });

  });
```

Comment: Are you wanting webpack to inline all of the dependencies or are you wanting runtime loading?  If runtime loading you can use requirejs instead of require.  Webpack will ignore requirejs.

Answer (score 0):

They work in a similar way, i.e. each array of modules will be bundled into a separate chunk and then the Webpack runtime will async fetch them serially.